# Lazyloading like googlenewstand app

Tags: android, listview, imageview, lazy-loading, android-lazyloading

I am currently doing a project which needs to load images in a listView with some text from web.I am using **universal image loader library**,every thing work fine images are loading perfectly without any problem, but my requirement is that if there is no image in a specfic url, i dont want to show that image view in the listview row.which is similer  to the news stand app of google.

[image]

in the above screen of the newsstand app if there is no image the imageview is not shown and the text will fill to the total width of the cell or row in the listview.How can i achieve this requirement.i have goggled  but did not get any right solution or clue to  fix this issue,can any one give any snippet or any idea  to sort out this issue.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your adapter, when you call the library to display the image, if there is no image url just set the visibility of your ImageView to GONE (and VISIBLE again when there is an url).

If you want to wait that the image is completely loaded to make the ImageView visible, you'll need to register a loading listener. See [here](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader#complete).

Comment: i set the visiblity gone in load failed but while i scroll listview its shows reposition of image and set to normal  when i stop scrolling

Comment: In your getView method, set the ImageView drawable at null everytime before loading the new one.